# Two similar parent modules with different version numbers with submodules - maven

Tags: maven, module, dependencies, installation

I have two parent modules in two different projects. But those are actually same but different version numbers.

Now each of these two modules contains 3 sub-modules. Versions of submodules in each of the parent modules are same. (same groupid, artifactId, and version numbers)

ParentA is already installed. ParentB is not. I am just just waiting to run either clean install or install on parentB.

1. Would that mess up repository? Will there be any issues?
2. What happens if both these parents have a same parent, when I run clean install (may be different versions)?

Comment: Try it and tell us what happens!

Comment: I do not want to mess up things and then spend hours on fixing it. So I wanted to find out if any one has experience doing this. :-)

Comment: Can you please provide the XML of the groupId/artifactId/version from your two projects?